# Inverter Lista Simples

Tags: java, lista

> **EXERCÍCIO: Escreva um método que inverta uma lista ligada:**
>
>   **Entrada:** 10, 99, 101, 666
>   **Resultado Esperado:** 666, 101, 99, 10

Pensei em seguir a seguinte lógica: 
Chegaria até o ultimo elemento (666) com p e no penultimo com q (101), mandaria o p.prox indicar até o q (ou seja, invertendo esses dois, fazendo o 666 - nova cabeca - indicar para o 101). Ai, num laço, faria ele repetir esse processo só que indo até o anteantepenultimo (99) e ate o antepenultimo (10), invertendo eles também, até chegar no final. Porém, algo está dando errado e não consigo achar o que. Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
class E4 {

    ListaSimples e4 = new ListaSimples();
    public void inverterLista () {
        e4.insere(10);
        e4.insere(99);
        e4.insere(101);
        e4.insere(666);
        int nElementos = 4;
        int n;
        int k = nElementos;

        for (int i=0; i<nElementos; i++) {
            n = 1;
            No p = e4.cabeca;
            No q = e4.cabeca;

            // nessa parte faz com que ele chegue ate o numero e na
            // proxima vez, ate um numero menor e assim vai
            while (n<k) {
                q = p;
                p = p.prox;
                n++;
            }
            p.prox = q;
            k--;
        }

        for (int m=0; m<nElementos; m++){
            No imprimir = e4.cabeca;
            System.out.print(imprimir.letra+" ");
            imprimir = imprimir.prox;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        E4 e4 = new E4 ();
        e4.inverterLista();
    }

}
```

Comment: então é só criar um método recursivo que entre dentro da pilha até a ultima posição e comece imprimir de trás pra frente (cc @JeffersonQuesado)

Comment: @Everson recursivo, iterativo, e força bruta num vetor. Estou terminando esse último ponto mais por questões de completude do que necessidade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversas alternativas para se fazer essa inversão. Tenha em mente que você não pode perder o próximo elemento da lista, você deve sempre manter uma referência para ele.

Eu gosto da alternativa recursiva para essa questão, mas essa é uma recursão muito simples, então vou mostrar seu equivalente iterativo.

## Versão recursiva

Uma inversão de lista simplesmente ligada é o processo de fazer o seguinte:

```
ancestral -> atual -> descendente
// magia da inversão 
ancestral <- atual <- descendente
```

Basicamente consiste de dois passos:

1. Faz o atual apontar para o ancestral
2. Faz a inversão do descendente

A ordem dos passos é irrelevante, desde que seja sempre conhecido o valor do `atual` e do `descendente`. Assim, vou criar um método `inverte` que receberá um hipotético `ancestral` e um `atual`. Note que o primeiro elemento da lista não tem ancestral, portanto posso chamar ele de `null` (ou pode ser um elemento guardião, tanto faz). Como não tenho garantia de que o último elemento da lista aponta para o valor nulo, vou passar também a posição do elemento atual e a quantidade de elementos da lista.

Estratégia a ser seguida:

1. Se não cheguei no fim (`posAtual` < `tamanho`), faço os passos 2 e 3
2. Chamo inverter com o elemento `atual.prox` no argumento para `atual`, `atual` no argumento `ancestral` e `posAtual + 1` no argumento para `posAtual`
3. `atual.prox = ancestral`

Note que se eu guardar o valor de `atual.prox` na variável `descendente`, eu posso inverter os passos 2 e 3. Em Java, eu vou chamar a recursão assim:

```
No novaCabeca = inverte(null, e4.cabeca, 0, nElementos);
e4.cabeca = novaCabeca; // para manter a cabeça válida
```

> Eu particularmente sou partidário de ter um contador de elementos dentro de `ListaSimples`, ou de ter a garantia que o último elemento aponta para `null` ou para um elemento guardião.

A recursão é implementada assim:

```
public static No inverter(No ancestral, No atual, int posAtual, int nElementos) {
    // passo 1: se for além do tamanho da lista, não processa nada
    if (posAtual >= nElementos) {
        return ancestral; // último nó válido
    }
    // passo 2: inverter a lista descendente
    No fimLista = inverter(atual, atual.prox, posAtual + 1, nElementos);
    // passo 3: inverter o nó atual
    atual.prox = ancestral;

    return fimLista;
}
```

Por curiosidade, essa aqui foi uma recursão de cabeça, pois o passo recursivo está no começo. A memória demandada para fazer essa recursão é `o(nElementos)`, tempo de execução também é `o(nElementos)`.

## Transformando em iteração

Vou transformar essa função primeiramente em uma recursão de cauda, para então remover o passo recursivo e tornar totalmente iterativo.

Para transformar em recursão de cauda, basta inverter os passos 2 e 3. Como dito acima, só é necessário uma variável para fazer isso:

```
public static No inverter(No ancestral, No atual, int posAtual, int nElementos) {
    // passo 1: se for além do tamanho da lista, não processa nada
    if (posAtual >= nElementos) {
        return ancestral; // último elemento válido
    }
    // reservando o valor do próximo 
    No prox = atual.prox;
    // passo 3: inverter o nó atual
    atual.prox = ancestral;
    // passo 2: inverter a lista descendente
    return inverter(atual, prox, posAtual + 1, nElementos);
}
```

Note que `posAtual` está servindo de índice de iteração, então podemos trocar tudo isso por um `for`, onde a condição de parada é a condição de parada do fim da recursão:

```
public static void inverterIterativo(ListaSimples l, int nElementos) {
    // simulando primeira chamada recursiva, note que os valores são os mesmos
    No ancestral = null;
    No atual = l.cabeca;
    for (int posAtual = 0; posAtual < nElementos; posAtual++) {
        No prox = atual.prox; // guarda o descendente para inverter no próximo passo
        atual.prox = ancestral; // inverte o atual

        // quando da chamada iterativa, atual é chamado com o valor de prox e ancestral com o valor de atual

        ancestral = atual;
        atual = prox;
    }

    // note que o último elemento válido ficou armazenado na variável ancestral
    l.cabeca = ancestral;
}
```

Note que esse método agora utiliza memória adicional constante `o(1)`, em contraponto à memória adicional da recursão que é `o(nElementos)`. O tempo, entretanto, continua no mesmo comportamento assintótico de `o(nElementos)`.

## Outras alternativas?

No momento, eu penso como outra alternativa escrever em um vetor de tamanho `nElementos` e copiar de volta para os nós da lista. Aqui teremos uma inversão de valores, não de endereços. Como você está fazendo um exercício, creio que essa vai ser a alternativa que daria menos pontos para você, mas continua fazendo a inversão (e acho uma curiosidade válida).

Note que vai ser necessário percorrer a lista duas vezes agora, e que é usada memória adicional de `o(nElementos)`.

```
public static void inverterIterativo(ListaSimples l, int nElementos) {
    int[] valores = new int[nElementos];
    // primeira iteração: povoa o vetor
    for (int i = 0, No atual = l.cabeca; i < nElementos; i++, atual = atual.prox) {
        valores[i] = atual.letra;
    }
    // segunda iteração: transmite os valores do vetor para os nós
    for (int i = nElementos - 1, No atual = l.cabeca; i >= 0; i--, atual = atual.prox) {
        atual.letra = valores[i]; // posição de i varia de traz para frente
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito o a dúvida, mas para inverter as posições, você pode fazer assim:

**1)** Cria um contador na classe e o incremente dentro do método `insere` da classe `ListaSimples`:

```
public void insere(int numero) {
    // INSTRUÇÕES PARA ADICIONAR NA LISTA
    cont++;
}
```

**2)** Faça um laço que decremente o valor da variável `cont`:

```
int j = 0;

for (int i = cont; i > 0; i--) {
    numerosAoContrario[j] = numerosInformados[i];
    j++;
}
```

A variável `i` vai receber a quantidade de números informados pelo método `insere` e o laço vai decrementar de um em um o valor até chegar em zero (isso significa que você está acessando os valores de trás para frente).

Já a variável `j`, será instanciada fora do laço e incrementada dentro dele, logo `numerosAoContrario[0] = numerosInformados[4]` (como no seu exemplo).

Comment: Para o laço funcionar sempre com a variável `j`, após o fim dele, zere a variável.

Comment: o problema da presente questão é sobre listas, não sobre vetores. Apesar de serem tipos de dados de armazenamento posicional, listas não são indexadas, e também tem outros comportamentos que não condizem com vetor, assim como vetor tem comportamento que não condiz com lista. [Essa outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217755/64969) trata de vetores, caso tenha algo a acrescentar