# Reverter as posições

Tags: java, array

```
 package pag1;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ex3 {
   public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);

    int posicao = 0;
    int[] numeros = new int [5];
    System.out.println("Digite 5 números: ");

    while (posicao < numeros.length){
        numeros [posicao] = x.nextInt();
        posicao++;          
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
    Arrays.sort(numeros, 0, numeros.length);
    System.out.print("[" + numeros[4] + ", " + numeros[3] + ", " + numeros[2] + ", " + numeros[1] + ", " + numeros[0] + "]");

  }

}
```

Como posso fazer para mostrar os itens do array revertidos sem ser usando essa gambiarra que fiz no final?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217632/64969

Comment: Se os números podem vir de ordem arbitrária, chamar o `sort` não vai te ajudar

Comment: Realmente, são bem parecidas, não tinha visto a questão dele. Mas queria saber se existe comando pra reverter as posições do array, se ele lê por exemplo do 0 ao 4, se teria algum comando pra ler a partir do 4 até a posição 0.

Comment: uma maneira simples que me vem a mente é colocar no final algo como, System.out.print("[" + numeros[4] + ", " + numeros[3] + ", " + numeros[2] + ", " + numeros[1] + ", " + numeros[0] + "]"); mas me parece uma gambiarra feia.

Comment: minha resposta segue a ideia dessa "gambiarra", só que generalizando e fazendo a troca ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trocar dois números inteiros de variáveis, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;

int swapAux = a;
a = b;
b = swapAux;
```

Podemos usar a mesma lógica para trocar inteiros em posições do vetor. Seja `i` uma posição num vetor de `n` elementos, indexado por 0, o elemento oposto a `i` é `n - i - 1`.

> Faça a verificação para o `i` como sendo o primeiro elemento `i = 0` e como sendo o último elemento `i = n - 1` caso não esteja convencido da fórmula

Para garantir que vamos trocar os elementos apenas uma vez de posição, podemos iterar apenas até a metade. Portanto, a inversão de um vetor pode ser feita assim:

```
public void inverteVetor(int[] vet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length / 2; i++) {
        int reverso = vet.length - i - 1;

        int swapAux = vet[i];
        vet[i] = vet[reverso];
        vet[reverso] = swapAux;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando as novas funcionalidades de streams do Java 8 e lambdas basta fazer:

```
int[] numerosInvertidos = IntStream.range(0, numeros.length)
                                   .map(i->numeros[numeros.length-i-1]).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numerosInvertidos)); //mostrar o array todo
```

Em que o `map` mapeia cada valor para o seu inverso através das posições do array. Da `0` para a `4`, `1` para a `3`, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão de que **NUNCA** vou me acostumar com esse paradigma funcional no Java. É lindo e estranho tudo ao mesmo tempo

Comment: É uma questão de habito. O que é certo é que ajuda a ter o código bem mais curto.