# Lista encadeada em C - Invertendo os nós de maneira recursiva

Tags: c, recursão, lista-encadeada

Estou seguindo as notas de [Projetos de Algoritmo](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/index.html) do professor Paulo Feofiloff, e estou com dificuldades em resolver uma questão do capítulo de [Listas Encadeadas](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html), transcrito à seguir:

> Exercícios 5
>
> 7. Escreva uma função que inverta a ordem das células de uma lista encadeada (a primeira passa a ser a última, a segunda passa a ser a
>      penúltima etc.). Faça isso sem usar espaço auxiliar, apenas alterando
>      ponteiros. Dê duas soluções: uma iterativa e uma recursiva.

Eu consegui chegar em uma solução iterativa, porém não consegui nem desenhar uma solução recursiva.

Então peço que me direcionem pra solução recursiva deste problema. Obrigado!

Segue código da solução iterativa (favor indicar melhorias).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

/*
Esta função recebe uma lista encadeada de inteiros e inverte a posição das
células desta lista usando apenas ponteiros. Ex.: o primeiro nó troca de lugar 
com o último, o segundo nó troca de lugar com o antepenúltimo, etc. 
*/

// versão iterativa
void swap_nodeI (NODE **head) {
    // if list is empty or there is only one node, nothing to do
    if (*head == NULL) return;

    // declare variables for first half of the list
    NODE *prevX = NULL, *currX = *head;
    int countX = 1;

    // declare variables for second half of the list
    NODE *prevY = NULL, *currY = *head; 
    int countY = 1;

    // count nodes (countY)
    for (; currY->next != NULL; currY = currY->next, ++countY);

    // swap nodes
    NODE *temp;
    int i, j;
    while (countX < countY) {

        // setup pointers
        for (currY = *head, i = 1; i != countY; ++i) {
            prevY = currY;
            currY = currY->next;
        }
        for (currX = *head, j = 1; j != countX; ++j) {
            prevX = currX;
            currX = currX->next;
        }

        // swap X and Y
        if (prevX != NULL) prevX->next = currY;
        else *head = currY;
        if (prevY != NULL) prevY->next = currX;
        else *head = currX;
        temp = currY->next;
        currY->next = currX->next;
        currX->next = temp;

        // update counters
        ++countX;
        --countY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu já respondi uma questão assim...

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217757/64969

Comment: Valeu, Jefferson! Eu tava quebrando a cabeça pra achar uma solução recursiva que não envolvesse informar o tamanho da lista encadeada. Você sabe se é possível assim? Obrigado, de qualquer forma. Vou tentar implementar com a sua estratégia.

Comment: Tem sim, a ideia é fazer a inversão entre o anterior e o seguinte, `anterior -> atual -> seguinte` para `anterior <- atual <- seguinte`

Comment: Meu Deus.. só agora a ficha caiu.. Eu tava fixado em trocar pares equidistantes! Quando bastava inverter a lista inteira..

Comment: Por favor, não utilize a pergunta para postar a resposta. Utilize o campo abaixo para responder com a sua solução.

Comment: Responder à minha pergunta?

Comment: Sim, no campo abaixo acima do botao "publique sua resposta"

Answer (score 1):

Após perceber que a estratégia de inverter a lista atende ao enunciado, tudo clareou. Eu estava fixado em tratar os pares equidistantes da lista, dificultando a solução. Inclusive a solução iterativa ficaria muito mais simples:

```
void reverse(NODE **head) {
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    NODE *curr = *head;
    NODE *next;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    *head = prev;
}
```

Segue solução recursiva:

```
void reverseR(NODE **head) {

    /* Tratar lista vazia */
    if (*head == NULL) return;

    /* Atribuir um ponteiro para o nó atual
       e outro ponteiro para o restante da lista */
    NODE *curr;
    NODE *rest;
    curr = *head;
    rest = curr->next;

    /* Retornar ao chegar no final da lista */
    if (rest == NULL) return;

    /* Chamar a recursão até atingir o final da lista */
    reverseR(&rest);

    /* Inverter os nós e acertar a cabeça da lista */
    curr->next->next = curr;
    curr->next = NULL;
    *head = rest;
}
```

Comment: Essa solução é iterativa, não recursiva. Então ainda falta uma metade da questão

Comment: Só fui mexer com isso hoje. Mas já adicionei a versão recursiva. Tem sugestão pra melhorar os códigos? Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou a primeira função?

Comment: YODA, pelo que me lembro ela até funcionou.. mas quando eu pensei na "swap_nodeI" eu não havia entendido muito bem o conceito do exercício. A função "reverse" é bem mais eficiente.